# center a div inside another div vertically

Tags: html, css

Lets say I have this simple html page:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>HEADER</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="box">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My header is fixed and the content should be beneath it and with height 100% of what ever left of the body.
I've already done that with this style:

```
*{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.header {
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    padding-top: 38px;
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

.content {
    flex: 1;
}

.box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Here's how the page looks for now: https://elbargho.github.io/sudoku/centerdiv.html
now I'm trying to center the `box` div horizontally and vertically in relative to the full body - the header size
what I've tried to do:

1. margin-top: 50% - for some reason the box went all the way down to the bottom
2. setting the position of `content` div to relative, and of `box` div to absolute - the `content` div overlapped the fixed `header`

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/bNdmnJZ

Comment: Try this `.box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}`

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov exactly

Comment: @Abdallah Barghouti, I gave you the solution below

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov That worked perfectly. But what if I had a text or a div in .container that I dont want to center, what can I do in this situation?

Comment: @Abdallah Barghouti, They also appear in the center, like the yellow square. Can you show your future site layout? And you can already make the right decision for you.

Comment: if I do the same solution I will have now overflow

Comment: Just show how your layout should look like and we'll help you arrange the elements correctly. Here all the answers are similar, with the use of `flex`.

Comment: Here's what I wanted: https://ibb.co/r5pgyWX the arrows in the photo should be equal in height

Comment: here's what I've got https://elbargho.github.io/sudoku/centerdiv.html

Comment: you put the yellow square in a separate class `center`, and you did it right) Your site looks good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here solution:

```
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set content class as

```
.content {
    /* flex: 1; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```css
*{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.header {
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    padding-top: 38px;
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

.content {
    /*flex: 1; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>HEADER</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="box">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you need. Documented in the code.

```css
* {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Modified */
.header {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  /* position: fixed; */
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  padding-top: 38px;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* Modified */
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Modified */
.content {
  /*flex: 1;*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: inherit;
}

.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use CSS Transform.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* horizontal center */
  margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Check out this website for all CSS centering help:
http://howtocenterincss.com/